# JS - get the member names of the class

Tags: javascript

I need to get member names (fields and methods) of the class or at least field names. For example I have the following class:

```
function PersonClass(){
  this.name="Jack";
  this.surname="SomeOne";
}
```

I have two solutions:

1. convert class to string and use regex
2. create method in class and using `for ... in this` get the members. However to run this method I need to create instance of the class.

I don't like both of them. Are there another solutions to get member names?

Comment: What do you mean by "class"?  JavaScript (pre-ES6) doesn't have classes.

Comment: Could you please explain your first option? It seems like you have something specific in mind. Are you talking about the constructor function? Do you control the code for the "class"?

Comment: @user2570380: I think he means dynamically in the application.

Comment: MooTools, jQuery, ExtJS, ..?

Comment: @six fingered man I edited

Comment: Pointy, JavaScript does have classes http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @user3063182 nope JavaScript does not have classes. JavaScript has prototype inheritance

Comment: @user3063182: Nowhere on that page does it use the word "class".

Comment: `var props = Object.keys(new PersonClass);`, not considered as good practice though.

Comment: @Teemu  It will require creating instance. See #2

Comment: Well, looking at the comments in this post, looks like alternatives are running out. Without an instance the only chance is your own #1, if you don't want to use Jamiec's prototype approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you going to do with the member names once you get them?

Why would you imagine that you could somehow obtain them when they are not even in existence until the constructor is called to create a specific instance?

Why would you believe that you could write a regexp so smart that it could parse JS well enough to pull out all the properties (not "fields")? How could such a regexp possibly identify a property which is added dynamically and conditionally by a prototype method defined elsewhere?

If you want to record such metadata, then just do so explicitly, most likely as a property on the constructor:

```
PersonClass.properties = ['name', 'surname'];
```

In some far-away version of JS, you may be able to do this via annotations:

```
@properties('name', 'surname')
function PersonClass() { ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. What for I need them I described in details here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73697/binding-model-to-view

Comment: You have a blindingly massive task ahead of you. What do you hope to accomplish that other similar binding frameworks do not already? Do you realize that whatever you build will instantly be outdated when `Object.observe` or `Proxy` hits the browsers? Why on earth are you worrying about IE8 in this day and age? For your clients who insist on IE8 support, just keep writing jQuery.

Comment: You even can't imagine how I hate IE8 and many other MS products. But you should ask not me but Bill Gates why even in Win7 it's default browser. About other frameworks - I started from angular and I finished here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467908/angularjsrequirejs-and-modules my conclusion it's bad for large application and besides its structure doesn't suit well for other our framework + I want realize "runtime compilation at request - not wait untill page is totally loaded". I looked at backbone and ember - their templates not good for me.

Comment: @PashaTurok The browser on Win7 can easily be upgraded to IE9, or 10, or 11. There is an overwhelming trend to abandon IE8. I share your pain with Angular, Ember et al. Good luck with your project. However, I recommend you look forward rather than back.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `prototype` of the object. For example, given this definition of a class-like javascript object:

```
var MyObject = function() {

};
MyObject.prototype.foo = 3;
MyObject.prototype.bar = function(){
    alert("bar");
};
```

This will work (No instance required):

```
for(var x in MyObject.prototype)
    alert(x);  // alerts "foo" and then "bar"
```

In the same way an instance would usually work

```
var o = new MyObject();
for(var x in o)
    alert(x);  // also alerts "foo" and then "bar"
```

Comment: No, it's not good. The first way will display only prototype fields and methods but not those, which you can declare in MyObject. For the second way see 2.